# Splitting page layout

Tags: usability, experience

I'm working on a website for searching electronic projects.

I'm considering two options:

1. A user visits the website and gets redirected to the landing page. The landing page explains what they can do on the website. Popular projects and newsletter inputs are shown with a footer. When they click the "Browse" button on the landing page they get redirected to a search page. On the search page there is an input field with ajax reloading and filters that update projects live based on user input.
2. When the user visits the website they are immediately redirected to the search page. The landing page doesn't exist.

I'm worried that if I don't say what my site is intended for the user will leave. And if I have the landing and search pages separately, I'm afraid the extra step will be too much. And I need to optimize the search part so that a user can clearly see live updates based on their input.

Here is a [quick mockup of my layout](http://img.hr/aagO).

Comment: Why are you redirecting at all? Let people get to whatever page they were going to without a redirect. If people don't know what the site is for, that's a broader branding/graphic design/content issue that needs to be resolved.

Comment: To add to @DA01's comments, it also seems as though you are taking the user to different locations from what they click on. They click on browse, but taken to search? That makes no sense. Careful with those patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not combine both on a single page?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How many times would a user land on an individual page unless he was directed there via a search engine or from an inbound link?  It is entirely likely that the user searched for and chose to land on that particular page. Why would you take him away from there and ask him to search again?

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on your target group - if it is a community of aficionados, then the immediate search page is good for them. If you're mostly recruiting one-time users from search engines, you might want to show them first that they reached a reliable site (on the landing page).

I do not, however, quite understand the exclusiveness of your alternatives: You can put the search field on the landing page, and when the user keys in something, the newsletter content can be replaced by search hits. That approach will also avoid the mostly empty initial state of a search-only page.

Answer (score 1):

For such cases I almost always use the so-called "Primary marketing message" in header (usually in visual hierarchy it stands right after logo). It can be a short neutral phrase ("Technical supply equipment") or marketing slogan, but in any case it *should* cleary describe the intention of the website — that is why purely emotional slogans fail (like something senseless "Bringing dreams to you business").

You can also support this message without distracting users by adding tiny boxes with attractive image, more extended messages, links to read more (probably it can lead to something more descriptive, like your landing) and the button "Close". Popups work worse, because they *always* require user's action and it can be frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a landing page and instead make your search automatically filter the results as the user types.

As soon as there are no search results you should display suggestions similar to your landing page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution to this problem, and that is making a simple welcome popup. On first view, the site will darken most of the ui, and display a small subtle popup box, which will cease to display unless the user checks off a box. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sending everyone through this splash / landing page may: ***increase user drop off rate*** and ***increase visitor frustration***.

**Why?** - Users coming to your website via search engines or a shared deep link will be instantly redirected to a page they were not expecting. In many similar cases those visitors go back and try a different website

#### Drop off rate is still high

> I'm worried that if I don't say for what my site is intended the user will leave.

That is a very different problem that is usually solved in a different manner and not via a redirect. This is purely content issue.

You will need to:

1. Take a look your traffic flow patterns and see where users are landing
2. What are the most common sections / content people are looking for
3. Invest and define great IA

These three things will help you create a better experience for your viewer by providing the most critical information upfront and allow them to see a clear path to other sections / functionality of the site

Answer (score 0):

You can show landing slider as a first section which can be used to attract visitor with the image and rich context.

Second section : 
you can show most popular or 3-4 popular categories of your products in block style.

Third section : 
Can be used to show 4 products block in carousel style.so user can at least view 5-10 products by sliding out 
And you can give view more buttom at the bottom of it.

Fourth and fifth section :
Your companys important features and footer